# Fastest way to return multiple match values in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to see if there's a macro that can speed up a multiple match formula I'm using in a file.

The formula is:

> `=IFERROR(INDEX(Data!$D:$D,SMALL(IF('Department 1'!$A$1=Data!$B:$B,ROW(Data!$B:$B)-MIN(ROW(Data!$B:$B))+1,""), ROW(Data!A1))),"Enter New Client Name")`

In a workbook, There's three worksheets: Data, Department 1, and Department 2.

In the "Data" worksheet, Column B has a list of all the departments (i.e. Department 1 and Department 2) and Column C has a list of Clients that belong to each department.

The Department 1 and Department 2 worksheets have the exact match formula that's looking up the list of clients based on its department name.

This formula is runs pretty slow even if I'm just looking up 10 clients so I'm wondering if it's possible to speed it up using a macro?

I checked this website and found something that was able to look up 40,000 entries instantly (see below), but it's only running the macro on one worksheet.  The real workbook I'm working in has over 30 different departments and I need the formula to run on all 30 worksheets so that the list of clients is unique to the department.

I apologize in advance if the instructions are not as clear, I was hoping I could upload a sample file, but since I'm new here I didn't see an option to upload.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim vLoookupVal As Variant
    Dim vValues As Variant
    Dim aResults() As Variant
    Dim lResultCount As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lIndex As Long

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws1 = Me                    'This is the sheet that contains the lookup value
    Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")   'This is the sheet that contains the table of values

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, ws1.Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        ws1.Columns("B").ClearContents   'Clear previous results
        vLoookupVal = Intersect(Target, ws1.Range("A1")).Value
        lResultCount = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws2.Columns("A"), Target.Value)
        If lResultCount = 0 Then
            MsgBox "No matches found for [" & vLoookupVal & "]", , "No Matches"
        Else
            ReDim aResults(1 To lResultCount, 1 To 1)
            lIndex = 0
            vValues = ws2.Range("A1:B" & ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value
            For i = LBound(vValues, 1) To UBound(vValues, 1)
                If vValues(i, 1) = vLoookupVal Then
                    lIndex = lIndex + 1
                    aResults(lIndex, 1) = vValues(i, 2)
                End If
            Next i
            ws1.Range("B1").Resize(lResultCount).Value = aResults
        End If
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: In order to provide a sample file for others to help you, you need to upload it to some sharing site (OneDrive and DropBox are two examples), and then edit your original question to include the link to that file.  This forum, itself, does not provide the storage for those files.  You should remove any sensitive information from your file before uploading.

Comment: You say *Column C has a list of Clients* but your formula says `Data!$D:$D`

Comment: Of course it's slow! You're asking it to process all 1048576 cells in a column (Data!$B:$B). Just a single instance of the formula you posted is having to process more than 3 million cells, an astonishing amount for a single formula. Do you really have data extending all the way to the very end of the worksheet? Or were you perhaps hoping to 'cover your bases' for a potentially-expanding dataset? If so, you should know that, with array formulas, ALL CELLS within the range passed are processed, whether technically beyond the last-used cell in that range or not.

Comment: Also, for large datasets and in cases where the formula is being copied to many cells, IFERROR can be extremely resource-heavy in this type of set-up: https://superuser.com/questions/812727/look-up-a-value-in-a-list-and-return-all-multiple-corresponding-values

Comment: Thank you to everyone responding.  I will respond in the order of the comments.

I will try uploading the sample file to a site so i can share.

I meant column D.  But I actually need both C and D to be copied over to the Department tabs.

The idea was to make sure I'm capturing the new range of data in case it expands.

I was hoping there was a vba to help so I didn't have to use slow formulas lol

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to allocate *Client names* to the *Department sheets* which they belong to.

Below code will add the department sheets if they do not exist so you don't have to worry about adding department sheets.

Assuming your department names are in Sheet "Data" Column B, Client Names are in Sheet "Data" Column C, and they both have a header (your data start from 2nd row), and all input data to be inserted into Column A of Department sheets:

```
Sub MyClients()
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim wsname As String
lastrow = Worksheets("Data").Cells(Worksheets("Data").Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = 2 To lastrow
    wsname = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 2).Value
    On Error Resume Next
    Worksheets(wsname).Cells(Worksheets(wsname).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 3).Value
    If Err.Number = 9 Then
        Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 2).Value
        Worksheets(wsname).Cells(Worksheets(wsname).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 3).Value
    End If
Next i
Worksheets("Data").Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Tehscript, the vba worked perfectly.  Is it possible to tweak this to that both C and D gets copied over?
there's no need to create a new worksheet if it identifies a new department.  the list of departments are locked within a selection range so it's specific to someone that oversees the departments.

Comment: The part that copies your data to the other sheet is `Worksheets(wsname).Cells(Worksheets(wsname).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 3).Value`. `Cells(row_no,column_no)` is the key to your goal, so play with it and see what happens. If you don't try to understand it, you will always need others to do even the simplest things.

Comment: Thanks, Tehscript.  I took your advice and just added a second line and updated the parameters.  It took about 45 seconds to copy over two columns of data.. about 638 cells in total.  Is this the reason it took 45 seconds or just the nature of the code?

    Worksheets(wsname).Cells(Worksheets(wsname).Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Worksheets("RevData").Cells(i, 6).Value
    Worksheets(wsname).Cells(Worksheets(wsname).Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Worksheets("RevData").Cells(i, 7).Value